# If I have an image with a div wrapped around it, how do I make it only show a certain section of the image?

Tags: html, css

If I have an image with a div wrapped around it, how do I make it only show a certain section of the image?

```
<div id=#container"><img src="hello.jpg" /></div>
```

Lets say I want the image to only display a width of 200px and a height of 200px.  I also want it to start showing it 10pixels from the top, and 30 pixels to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `<div id="#container">` is absolutely positioned, you can use the clip property:

```
#container {
    /* top, right, bottom and left points of the rectangle */
    clip: rect(10px, 230px, 210px, 30px);
}
```

The above would create a rectangular clip with its top-left corner 10px from the top and 30px from the left.  Its bottom-right corner is 210px from the top and 230px from the left (which gives you your 200px of width and height).

You can read more about it [in this article](http://www.ibloomstudios.com/articles/misunderstood_css_clip/).

Answer (score 5):

You could put it as a background-image for the div, make it a block with set width/height & use background-position to get the position you wanted.

Comment: Depends on the purpose of the image - personally, sounds like it's presentational (i.e. not part of the content), in which case I would opt for this answer.

Comment: This was what I originally had, but it didnt work with what I was doing.  It's because I cant distort the image background in css2 anyways.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden
}
#container img {
    margin: -10px 0 0 -30px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
    padding-top  : 10px;
    padding-left : 30px;

}
#container img {
    width        : 200px;
    height       : 200px;
}
```

Image won't be stretched:

```
#container img {
    max-width    : 200px;
    max-height   : 200px;
}
```